# How can I get images from API in Custom print format instead of frappe files?

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I have created a custom print format where I can print all form data using Jinja but there are some base64 images that I am storing on external server and I want to get those images and display it on print page.

images are in base64 and I have tried localstorage it is working but need to get it form api each time I want to print.

is there a way to override the print class? if yes which class/file it is.

Comment: can u give an example, it's unclear to me

Comment: I just want to get images from an api call inside frappe erpnext custom print format

Comment: https://frappeframework.com/docs/v14/user/en/desk/printing#print-format-builder